# WCF Service added as a service reference shows up as a connected service with missing DataContracts

Tags: wcf

I have a solution where I add a `service reference` for a service and the service shows up as a `service reference` and everything works great. Very Happy.

In a separate solution I have created the service. Within this solution I have a project for unit testing the service. When I add a service reference for the service to the unit test project, the reference shows up as a `connected service` rather than the expected `service reference`, and I do not have access to classes specified by `[DataContract]` .

This behavior is not the same as installing the service on a different project, and it is preventing me from testing the service.

To recap, I have one service, installing it in two separate solutions produces different results. One solution the install works as expected and I have access to classes specified by `DataContract` and the other solution Installs the service and I do not have access to classes specified by `DataContract`. Both installed services provide all the methods exposed in the `interface`.

What can I add to help figure this out? I am not terribly familiar with services so please ask me questions to help improve this question.

****UPDATE****
What is working if I add a new project, then the service provides the data contracts. Something is going sour when I am updating the service references on an existing project. Obviously creating a new unit test project and moving everything in is a pain.....

Comment: Are you looking in the reference.vb file that gets created when you add a service reference via the UI? Are you using different versions of visual studio?

Comment: Have you tried adding the reference as a project reference rather than a service reference in the unit test project?

Comment: @spodger I first test the library via the reference to the project. Once that works I write a second test to test the service itself. So I reference both.

Comment: @Popo Same versions of Visual Studio. It's C#, it looks like the app.config file gets modified with the reference. With exception of the service namespace, which I changed on the tester, the code is identical

Comment: @Iannazzi Glad to hear you got it working.

Comment: @popo was working now is not

Comment: @Iannazzi do you need to add a reference in you unit test project for the namespace of the service to your references?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by a combination of restarting visual studio, restarting the computer, deleting the service reference, re-installing the service reference. I believe deleting the service reference then reinstalling using a different namespace ended up working. I also deleted the unit tester and rebuilt it, re-doing all references, installing the service under a new namespace, so that may have been the total fix.

****Update it broke again and this did not work*****

Comment: Update this issue showed back up and I do not have a solution that works